# Can a healthcare facility keep driver licenses

Tags: business, florida

If a person goes to visit a resident in a Florida healthcare facility can the facility demand to hold the persons drivers license until they leave?

Comment: Is a “healcare” facility a hospital with only podiatrists?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can. They can in fact entirely bar entry into their facility, require that you put down a damage deposit, or various other things. If the legislature wanted to, it could pass a law that prohibits a facility of some type from restricting access to the facility in a particular way (such as barring the common requirement to check in and check out); it is likely that the owners would successfully argue that such a law is not constitutional. There is no such law in Florida, so they can require you to check in and out, they can require you to show ID, and they can require you to surrender your ID in order to get compliance with the check-out requirement.

Comment: I thought that some states considered that a driver's license is the property of the state government, not of the license holder.  If so, it could be that the holder is not authorized to surrender it to the facility, or that the facility is not authorized to possess it.

Comment: In such states, if they exist, I would wonder how it could be legal to hand a DL to a non-government agent for inspection.